# Question about matrices with exponential notation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem in my book that reads, "Explain why the formula is not valid for matrices," with the formula,

$$(A + B) (A - B) = A^2 - B^2$$

I know that the answer is because there's no commutative property for multiplication of matrices/because $AB$ is probably not equal to $BA$.

My question is about the squared matrices -- earlier in this section my book introduced using exponents with matrices, and said that you can use exponential notation with *square* matrices. So wouldn't the formula also be invalid if $A$ and $B$ are not square? Does this formula just assume that $A$ and $B$ are square matrixes? If we're assuming that $A^2$ and $B^2$ are defined, then are we also assuming that the equation is defined even though it may not be valid; ie we're also assuming $AB$ and $BA$ are both at least defined even though they may not be equal? Should I assume that everytime I see a matrix raised to an exponent, it is assumed to be a square matrix?

Sorry, I just want to understand why my book can raise $A$ and $B$ to powers here without saying that they're square.

Answer (score 1):

$A^2$ isn't defined if $A$ isn't square. If you come across the expression $A^2$ in the book then it is implicit that $A$ is a square matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are not square (and of the same size), then $(A+B)(A-B)$ doesn't make sense at all

And yes, similarly writing $A^2$ only makes sense if $A$ is square. That's not different from writing $AA$, really, so you probably shouldn't think of the exponential *notation* as the culprit.

It is very common in discussions about matrices to assume (without saying it out loud) that the matrices in question are square. Unfortunately one often needs to guess whether that is the case from the context -- but here it is obvious because the expressions in question won't make sense otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Already said, but:

Indeed, for $AB$ and $BA$ both to make sense the two matrices should be square and of the same size.

Normally, it is understood that $\exp(A) = I + \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{t^k}{k!} A^k$ which makes sense only for square matrices.

NB: Some scientific computer languages does it differently, however. Matlab defines ${\rm expm}(A)$ to be the above exponential (and $A$ should be square), but ${\rm exp}(A)$ to be the matrix where exponential is taken in each element (and $A$ need not be square).